# Using Sed.exe to modify files with names that do not begin with specific characters

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, sed

I'm new to this stuff, so I hope in somebody's help.

I'm doing this on Windows Vista 32 bit version.

I have 2 folders on my desktop: folder_a (with sed.exe) and folder_b with these files:

- sand.txt
- tree.txt
- chair.txt
- xyz-fork.txt
- xyz-spoon.txt

If I run a batch file with this string:

```
call "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_a\sed.exe" -i "1c table-zeta" "C:\Users\X\Desktop\folder_b\*xyz*.txt
```

I'm able to change the first line of those files whose filename contains xyz.

Now what I want to do is change the first line of those files whose filename DOES NOT contain xyz; in this case only sand.txt, tree.txt and chair.txt.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little inelegant, but put this into your batch file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        ︙
for %%f in (*) do (
    set tempname=%%f
    set tempname=!tempname:xyz=!
    if %%f == !tempname! (put your sed command here) %%f
)
```

The `setlocal` command can be at the beginning of the batch file,
or right before the `for` loop, or anywhere in between. 
(I recommend putting it at the beginning of the batch file,
right after the `@echo off`.) 
Run `cmd /?` and `setlocal /?` for a bit more information about this command. 
Basically, it lets you handle variables in loops in a somewhat sane way.

I presume that you know enough about batch files that you understand
that `FOR variable IN (set) DO command`
loops over the filenames in *`set`* (which can include wildcards, like `*`),
setting the *`variable`* to each filename, and executing the *`command`*. 
The parentheses (after `do`, and at the end)
let us have a multi-line *`command`*. 
The normal variable syntax doesn’t work on `%%variable`s,
so we copy `%%f` to a temporary variable. 
Then we use the `%variable:str1=str2%`
(find and replace) form of variable expansion
to replace all occurrences of `xyz` in `%tempname%` with null.

… ***Except***, since we’re in a loop,
we have to use **`!`** instead of `%`
(this is where the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` comes in). 
Then we compare the abridged filename to the original name (still in `%%f`). 
If they’re equal, then there must not be any instances of `xyz`
in the filename, so we run your command. 
If they’re different, that means that the substitution
found at least one `xyz`, so we *don’t* run your command.

P.S. I believe that you don’t need the `call` command.